# {assertr} for multivariate conditional restriction

Tags: r, validation, conditional-statements, assertr

I would like to check a dataset for a multivariate conditional restriction, meaning that given certain values in certain variables, I expect certain values in other variables.

For example with `mtcars`, if `cyl` is 6 and `gear` is 3, then `vs` must be 1 and `am` must be 0. The assertion should fail if `cyl` is 6 and `gear` is 3, and `vs` must is NOT 1 and/or `am` is NOT 0. The assertion should also pass if `cyl` is NOT 6 or `gear` is NOT 3, regardless of the values of `vs` and `am`.

Is there a way to do this within {assertr} logic? Right now, I have two workarounds that are clunky and hard to follow.

Thank you for your suggestions!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(assertr)
library(assertive)

# This is the subset of mtcars that meets the testing requirements, and it passes.
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 6 & gear == 3) %>%
  filter(vs == 1 & am == 0)
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Valiant        18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

# With `assertr::assert_rows()`
mtcars %>%
  assertr::assert_rows(
    row_reduction_fn = function(data){
      data %>%
        filter(cyl == 6 & gear == 3) %>%
        assertr::verify(vs == 1 & am == 0, success_fun = success_logical)
    },
    predicate = assertive::is_true,
    cyl, gear, vs, am
  ) %>% 
  slice_head()
#>           mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4

# With `assertr::verify()`
mtcars %>%
  assertr::verify(nrow(filter(., cyl == 6 & gear == 3 & (vs != 1| am != 0))) == 0)%>% 
  slice_head()
#>           mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>